# Como remover um alert depois de selecionar outro em um select

Tags: javascript

Estou com o seguinte código:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control btn-form" id="select-category">
      <option selected hidden>Selecione uma categoria:</option>
      <option value="anu1">Anunciante1</option>
      <option value="anu2">Anunciante/option>
      <option value="anu3">Anunciante3</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#select-category').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'anu1'){     
      document.getElementById('alert-anu-1').style.display='block';   
  }

  if($(this).val() == 'anu2'){ 
    document.getElementById('alert-anu-2').style.display='block';
  }
  if($(this).val() == 'anu3'){ 
    document.getElementById('alert-anu-3').style.display='block';
  }
});
```

A ideia é ter uma lista e depois quando o usuário selecionar uma opção mostrar um "alert" em bootstrap. Ou seja, se o usuário selecionar o valor "anu1", mostra o alert "alert-anu-1", isso até então está funcionando. O que não estou conseguindo é limpar os valores.

Ex: se selecionar o valor anu1, mostra ele, mas se selecionar o valor anu2, tem que limpar o alert do anu1 e mostrar apenas o do anu2 e assim por diante....
Como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que basta algo como:

```
var alerts = $('[id^="alert-anu-"]');
$('#select-category').change(function() {
    alerts.hide();
    $('#alert-' + this.value).show();
});
```

Assim quando o select muda ele esconde todos os alertas e mostra só o que foi escolhido. Criei a variável `alerts` para ter esses elementos em cache e evitar ir ao DOM buscá-los muitas vezes.

Comment: Gostei desse jeito, mas não consigo executar. Os meus alerts e os meus valores estão escritos e não estão numerados como no exemplo.

Comment: O meu alert é tipo:  <div id="alert-anunciante-one" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <strong>PetBusca.</strong> Ferramenta bacana.... <a href="#" title="Saiba Mais">Saiba mais...</a>. 
                  </div>

Comment: @HitchLeonardo não faz diferênça se usas outros nomes para as IDs. Nesse caso podes usar `var alerts = $('[id^="alert-anunciante-"]');`, a chave aqui é `^=` que indica ID __começando com__ "xxx". Se quiseres um exemplo a funcionar junta um jsFiddle ou o código todo na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você não esta tirando o `display`, quando coloca com o `display = "block"` é preciso colocar `display = "none"`, assim vai esconder a mensagem.

```
$('#select-category').change(function(){
    for(var x=1;x<=3;x+=1) //apaga as 3 mensagens
        document.getElementById('alert-anu-'+x).style.display='none';

    if($(this).val() == 'anu1'){     
        document.getElementById('alert-anu-1').style.display='block';   
    }
    /*...*/
});
```